# My division statement keeps coming out to 0

Tags: java, loops, division

I am trying to make a program to calculate mpg on a road trip. I have it all laid out but on every run I get 0.0 for my mpg. I could use some help. I had to make mpg and totalMpg floats so I could do floating point division, if that doesn't make sense say so.

```
package Gas;

import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class GasTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int gas;
    int miles;
    int trips;
    float mpg;
    float totalMpg = 0;
    int tripCounter = 1;

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    out.println("Please input number of trips");
    trips = input.nextInt();

    while (tripCounter <= trips){
        out.println ("Input gallons of gas used");
        gas = input.nextInt();
        out.println("Input miles traveled on trip");
        miles = input.nextInt();
        mpg = (gas / miles) ;
        out.println("Your MPG for this trip was " + mpg);
        totalMpg = (mpg + totalMpg) / 2;
        out.println("Your overall MPG for all trips is " + totalMpg);
        tripCounter++;
    }


}

}
```

Comment: I suggest you use `double` as `float` rarely has enough precision.  It might do in this case, but I suggest getting used to using `double` as a good habit.

Comment: Your calculation for `totalMpg` is completely wrong. It is an estimate for the exponentially weighted average, but I suspect that is not what you intended.

Comment: How would you go about calculating totalMpg then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast `gas` to `float` in the below expression , if you don't want to declare `gas` as `float`.
This way you can take advantage of [Widening Primitive Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2), as mentioned in JLS.

```
mpg = ((float)gas / miles) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

If `miles` is greater than `gas`, as both of them are int, the result will be `0`, which will be stored as `0.0` when assigned to the float variable `mpg`.

You probably should declare them as float or cast `gas` when computing :

```
mpg = ((float)gas) / miles ;
```